# How to create stored procedure with multiple select in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I get a problem to create stored procedure in postgresql with multiple select, this is error that I get

> ERROR:  function result type must be specified SQL state: 42P13

and this is my query:

```
create or replace function user_info(
    functn integer
)
language sql 
as 
$$
begin
    
    if(functn = 1) then
        select email, user_name, address from user;
        
    else if(functn = 2) then
        select email, member_name, phone from member;
        
    else
        select email, admin_name, post_code from admin;
    
    end if;
    
end
$$;
```

please anyone help me to solve this problem, thanks.

Comment: You're doing `CREATE FUNCTION` without a `RETURNS` clause. (And also, your function doesn't *do* anything and returns nothing)

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few syntax errors in your function:

- You didn't specify the return type.
- Your function doesn't return anything.
- Correct syntax is `elsif` instead of `else if`.

Try this:

```
create or replace function user_info(
    functn integer
)
returns table(email text, name text, contact text)
language plpgsql 
as 
$$
begin
    if functn = 1 then
        return query select email, user_name, address from user;
        
    elsif functn = 2 then
        return query select email, member_name, phone from member;
        
    else
        return query select email, admin_name, post_code from admin;
    
    end if;

end;
$$
```